# How to use \@writefile without blocking a write stream?

Tags: auxiliary-files, write

From what I understand, to properly use `\@writefile` one has to block a write stream, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\tf@foo
\openout\tf@foo=\jobname.foo
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
    Writing ``#1'' to \texttt{\jobname.foo}!%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\@writefile{foo}{#1}}%
    }
\makeatother

\foo{Bar}

\end{document}
```

(This really creates a file `.foo` with one line containing `Bar`.)

Is there any way around blocking the write stream?

Comment: Do you mean that it should not be written immediately?

Comment: Well, it need not be. I'm slightly worried about occupying resources, that's all

Comment: not sure what you mean by block here, also you don't have to write indirectly via the aux file, unless you want to do that???

Comment: Well, you have 16 write resources, if I understand things correctly. Maybe I'm mistaken by something, but I hoped to be able to write to file without the file being open during the whole document... This should save some of them, no? Also, I would be more convenient in case of errors, but that's a side effect for now.

Comment: @yo': The `\@writefile` command is basically used only by `\addtocontents` to defer things to the various ToC - related files (i.e. `.toc`, `.lof` etc.) I don't get the question actually.

Comment: Ok, it seems I'm mistaken seriously. I'll re-think it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Another point: You can't reopen a stream for writing without overwriting the previous content. The ToC related stuff has to be written continously

Comment: you only need to hold the write stream open if you plan on writing again to the same file (as there is no "append")

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: the toc related stuff is not written continously to the toc-file. The toc-file is needed only at the end of the document when the aux-file is reread and the \@writefile commands executed (this means that you can put \tableofcontents (which contains the \newwrite for .toc) *behind* \section commands and it will still work). The memoir class delays the opening of the toc-file for writing and so allows two \tableofcontents commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I meant actually that the content meant for `toc` is written in place to the `.aux` file.